# PHP Jade Template parser

Tags: php, template-engine, pug

I'm looking for a PHP implementation of the Jade template engine used in NodeJS. I've recently tried [Jade.php](https://github.com/everzet/jade.php), but it is incomplete as it does not support inheritance or partials. I've also seen [PHPNativeJadeRenderer](https://github.com/superjimpupcake/PHPNativeJadeRenderer), but it relies on a `shell_exec` to parse the template file through the npm jade module and I'm not entirely comfortable with using that method.

Does anybody know of a complete PHP OOP port of the [Jade Template Engine](http://jade-lang.com)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Update (03.12.2015):*

It seems Tale Jade seems to be the most complete and most active integration of Jade into PHP.

https://github.com/Talesoft/tale-jade

*just as an update:*

it seems, this fork: https://github.com/SC7639/jade.php has the most features and nearly the most recent activity. (May 2016)

A chart of jade.php [fork/commit activity](https://github.com/everzet/jade.php/network) on GitHub.

Comment: I'd also like to introduce you to Tale Jade (http://jade.talesoft.io/), a PHP implementation of Jade that I wrote that aims to be the most complete one

Comment: @Torben great, integrated it with FlightPHP in no time.

Comment: @berkus Hey berkus, thanks for your feedback! Is there any way to contact you? I'd like to share your FlightPHP integration with other people :)

Comment: Actually, here is the _whole_ code I used  https://gist.github.com/berkus/f54347a4a1fd74e9e162

Comment: I have been using Smarty through the same kind of wrapper in Flight, so I didn't change _a single_ line of code at all, only switched templates to Jade. Perfect!

Answer (score 3):

One of the more up-to-date Jade parsers available for PHP is:

- https://packagist.org/packages/kylekatarnls/jade-php
- https://github.com/kylekatarnls/jade-php

I originally recommended https://github.com/everzet/jade.php a few years ago, which works quite well, though it has not been updated in several years.

Comment: first link returns 404.

Comment: Hi, thx to mention my fork, I try my best to increase the test cover and maintain jade-php. Soon I will release a version with many new features to get closer to the JS engine. Do not hesitate to send me pull requests.