# Using Jade on Apache

Tags: apache, pug

Is it possible to use [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) with Apache?

I am new to Node.js and I was recommended to use Jade instead of plain HTML, and I liked it. It's easier to work with.

But I am new to Node and don't know how to set things up the way I want, so I want to use PHP and Apache with Jade.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Quite a shame, maybe someone can post some kind of hack. Only time will tell :)

Comment: Oh, forget my previous comment. I've found one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355137/php-jade-template-parser

Comment: I suppose that's a solution. I was hoping it would be more down to the Apache level so if I used the jade extension it would figure. Thanks anyways. Maybe someone can find a Apache mod!

Comment: Can I mix PHP and Jade the way I do in HTML?